# Trigger is preventing a column to update

Tags: mysql, triggers, full-text-search

I am working on a project on which there is a trigger that storing data from other column's, like when data is inserted in table then a trigger get values from some specific columns and then store them in same tables column that is for getting the search keyword.

When I try to update or delete that search_keyword column's value, it doesn't work and remains the same when I update it and 'show 0 row affected' message in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You need to provide more information such as table structure and trigger code

Comment: and some sample data please.

Comment: For example  I am inserting a record in a table thats name is xyz and in that table i have some coloumns like a,b,c,d,e and search_keyword
there is a trigger that get value from a,b,c,d,e coloumns and then store it to search_keyword coloum so i can search data from that table.
when i want to edit search_keyword table it can not be updated i tried so much to edit it but it dos'nt work every time it remains same.
I also tried that why trigger preventing updation of table but cant find any thing

Comment: The reason the update is not occurring is because you change the column and it is changed, but then the trigger fires and updates the column back to what it believes it should be.  I think you have to tell us the deeper root meaning of why are you trying to override its default settings?  If it is just to add some keywords I would tell you to add another column which is integrated in the trigger so that you just update that column and it updates your search_keyword for you.